How to streamline identifying which lower and upper limits don't have 0?
I need to include in my graphs below regions where the confidence intervals do not include 0. At the moment, I'm doing this in a very long winded way.
e.g.
#first identify regions above 0 or below 0

sig1 <- with(df, lower > 0 & upper > 0 )
sig2 <- with(df, lower < 0 & upper < 0)

#then make new sig3, which includes the true from both sig1 and sig2 columns and use this for plot

df_new$sig3 <- df_new$sig1

positions <- which(df_new$sig2 == "TRUE")

df_new[positions, 9] <- "TRUE"


Any pointers to make this a bit quicker would be appreciated.

Could you edit your question to be reproducible, including cod and data to recreate the figure?

MIght note that   IFF    x * y < 0  then the interval [x,y] must contain zero.

Try something like the code between the comment lines below. It seems simpler to create a column that indicates whether the confidence interval does include zero (the include column) and then negate that (for the exclude column). Probably just having the include column would suffice for what you want to do?
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

N <- 50

# Create some sample data.
#
df <- data.frame(
  mean = rnorm(N)
) %>% mutate(
  lower = mean - 1,
  upper = mean + 1,
  t = row_number()
)

# =============================================================================

# Add columns that indicate whether the confidence intervals include or
# exclude zero.

df <- df %>% mutate(
  include = lower < 0 & upper > 0,
  exclude = !include
)

# =============================================================================

ggplot(df, aes(x = t, y = mean)) +
  geom_ribbon(aes(ymin = lower, ymax = upper), fill = "lightgrey") +
  geom_point(aes(col = exclude))

 I'm using mutate() from the dplyr package. You might want to consider this for manipulating columns in a data frame.
My plot is not as pretty as yours but I think it demonstrates the principle.


Plz see my comment on  the post itself; might speed up your code a bit.  Or maybe not.

Nice. Fewer operations, so bound to be faster. Clever approach. Not sure whether it makes too much practical difference in ths application.
